# Can't display JSON table object datas with angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, json, express

I try to display my datas in a html `<div>` from angularjs. 
When I do :

```
 <pre>
    {{otherResponse.confirmation | json}}
</pre>
```

I can see all my JSON datas in my `<pre>`, but I am not able to display them in an simple HTML `<div>` and I don't understand why. I use two different controllers, those datas are shared due to a service. Any help please ?

Bellow is my express post function with my JSON object

```
    app.post("/confirmation",function(req,res)
{
    var departure=req.body.departure;
    var destination=req.body.destination;
    var timeDestination=req.body.timeDestination;
    var timeDeparture=req.body.timeDeparture;
    var price=req.body.price;
    var firstName=req.body.firstName;
    var lastName=req.body.lastName;

    otherResponse = {
        "confirmation": [{
            "departure": departure,
            "destination": destination,
            "timeDeparture": timeDeparture,
            "timeDestination": timeDestination,
            "firstName": firstName,
            "lastName": lastName,
            "price": price
        }]
    };

    res.json(otherResponse);
});
```

Comment: You should post this as an answer to your own question instead of editing the answer into the question text. That way others can upvote and comment on the answer separately.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<pre>
    {{otherResponse.confirmation[0] | json}}
</pre>
```

Comment: I still can see my datas in my <pre></pre> tags but how to display it in a normal <div> ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

```
<ul ng-repeat="x in otherResponse.confirmation">
    <li>{{ x.departure }}</li>
</ul>
```